# Hibernate Annotations: Store an int in a varchar column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm using Hibernate Annotations.

In my POJO I have a year field which is an int.

I would like to persist this value in a char(4) column in my DB, and have hibernate convert the types back and forth.  Is there anyway I can easily do this (I started to look into the @Type annotation, but don't want to have to write my own custom type if possible)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the POJO 's field that is mapped to DB 's char(4) column is access by property , hibernate will  then call its setter and getter for the mapping between the database and the POJO . Thus , the conversion logic can be implemented inside the setter and getter of this property.  Besides , intDate should be mark as @Transient to tell hibernate to ignore mapping this field.

```
public class TableABC {

    private int id;
    private int intDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(length=4) 
    private  String getCharDate() {
        return String.valueOf(this.intDate);
    }

    private void setCharDate(String charDate) {
        try {
            this.intDate = Integer.parseInt(charDate);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Logic to handle when charDate cannot convert to integer 
            this.intDate = 0;
        }
    }

    @Transient
    public int getIntDate() {
        return intDate;
    }

    public void setIntDate(int intDate) {
        this.intDate = intDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it would meet my needs here.  Although, the more I read up on it, custom types don't seem too difficult, so maybe I'll experiment with that route as well, later.  This should get the functionality up and running for now.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on Hibernate sources, and I don't think there's a type that you could use for that:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type

But I'd encourage you to implement your own Type (maybe a Year type?), as it's not as difficult as it may sound :-)

The other solution, to handle the conversion in your setter, is also an option, but I wouldn't do it without a lot of testing and performance measurements.